# Unable to create AB OTA zip file in AOSP 11

Tags: android-source, android-11, ota

Unable to create AB OTA zip file in AOSP11.

Please find below error:

```
test@test:~/aosp/test1_android$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files out/dist/rockpi4b-target_files-eng.test.zip update.zip

2022-05-26 20:05:32 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:32 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:32 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:32 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:55 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop

2022-05-26 20:05:57 - ota_from_target_files - WARNING : Duplicate block difference found. 
Device specific block diff for partition 'system_ext' overrides the one in generic script.

2022-05-26 20:05:57 - ota_from_target_files - WARNING : Duplicate block difference found. Device specific block diff for partition 'product' overrides the one in generic script.

2022-05-26 20:05:57 - ota_from_target_files - WARNING : Duplicate block difference found. Device specific block diff for partition 'odm' overrides the one in generic script.

Compressing system.new.dat with brotli

Compressing vendor.new.dat with brotli

Compressing product.new.dat with brotli

Compressing odm.new.dat with brotli

Compressing system_ext.new.dat with brotli

write trust now...

write uboot now...

warning: no vbmeta.img in input target_files; not flashing vbmeta

wirte dtbo now...

no charge img; ignore it.

info: no resource image; ignore it.

no RKLoader.bin, ignore it.

info: no vendor_boot.img in input target_files; ignore it

info: no logo image; ignore it.
2022-05-26 20:07:28 - ota_from_target_files - ERROR   : 

   ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 2258, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 2237, in main
    source_file=OPTIONS.incremental_source)

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1980, in GenerateNonAbOtaPackage
    output_file)

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 880, in WriteFullOTAPackage

    FinalizeMetadata(metadata, staging_file, output_file, needed_property_files)

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1328, in FinalizeMetadata
    prelim_signing = ComputeAllPropertyFiles(input_file, needed_property_files)

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1314, in ComputeAllPropertyFiles
    SignOutput(input_file, prelim_signing)

  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 492, in SignOutput
    whole_file=True)

  File "/home/test/aosp/test1_android/build/make/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 1854, in SignFile
    proc.returncode, stdoutdata))

ExternalError: Failed to run signapk.jar: return code 1:

Error: Unable to access jarfile 

/home/test/aosp/test1_android/build/make/tools/framework/signapk.jar
```

Can you please help me , how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

ota_from_target_files acts different in android 11.

If you have executed "make dist", the otatools is put in out/dist/otatools.zip, or you can "make otatools-package", the otatools will put in out/target/product/xxxx/otatools.zip.

All the dependency is packed in otatools.zip, then you can use ota_from_target_files in otatools.zip to make ota zip.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. otatools.zip are generated in my out directory. Could you please share with me the steps to create a proper OTA .zip file? That will be very helpful for me.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/tools https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds

Comment: Yes, I have followed the same links, getting the same error after running "ota_from_target_files dist_output/tardis-target_files.zip ota_update.zip" this command.

Comment: Unzip otatools.zip, then run the ota_from_target_files in unziped directory

Comment: 2022-05-27 13:41:42 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop
2022-05-27 13:41:42 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop
2022-05-27 13:41:42 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop
2022-05-27 13:41:42 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/targetfiles-5bq28dqa/META/releasetools.py", line 54
    print "write parameter.bin now"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("write parameter.bin now")?

Comment: releasetools.py is the oem python script, which will be called by ota_from_target_files. It's set by TARGET_RELEASETOOLS_EXTENSIONS.  The post error is in releasetools.py. By the way, you have not enable a/b. If you have enable a/b, TARGET_RELEASETOOLS_EXTENSIONS will not be used.

Comment: its already set  ifeq ($(TARGET_RELEASETOOLS_EXTENSIONS),)
# default to common dir for device vendor
tool_extensions := $(TARGET_DEVICE_DIR)/../common
else
tool_extensions := $(TARGET_RELEASETOOLS_EXTENSIONS)
endif  in build/make/core/Makefile

Comment: Can you please help me to share any ref links , I will understand more.

Comment: Now error is not coming but getting below massage 2022-05-27 15:43:16 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop
2022-05-27 15:43:16 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop

Comment: Compressing system.new.dat with brotli
Compressing vendor.new.dat with brotli
Compressing product.new.dat with brotli
Compressing odm.new.dat with brotli
Compressing system_ext.new.dat with brotli
write trust now...
write uboot now...
warning: no vbmeta.img in input target_files; not flashing vbmeta
wirte dtbo now...
no charge img; ignore it.
info: no resource image; ignore it.
no RKLoader.bin, ignore it.
info: no vendor_boot.img in input target_files; ignore it
info: no logo image; ignore it.

Comment: You should set AB_OTA_UPDATER to true if you want to use A/B

Answer (score 0):

After you build AOSP code successfully,you must set DIST_DIR as follows:

```
. build/envsetup.sh && lunch {your_target}
mkdir dist_output
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
```

Comment: Error is coming in next step after giving below command any solution for that? ./build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files dist_output/target_files-eng.admin.zip update.zip